# How to : Run a python script in windows command line background at a precise hour of the day ?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program that calculates some data from MySQL database and store them in a MongoDB database, and I want to run this program in windows command line and execute the function every 9 am of everyday.

Comment: You probably want the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to leave the program running 24/7 and just run the function at 9 AM every day, this will do the job.

```
from subprocess import getoutput
from time import sleep

while 1:
    time = getoutput('time /t')
    if time == '09:00 AM':
        myfunction()
        sleep(85000)
    sleep(10)
```